# How to create a copy constructor and use a constructor as a function argument

Tags: c++

at the beginning I would like to appologize for the title of this thread. I was not sure about it, so I will explain what I would like to achieve.
Lets get started :)

My code:

```
 class CCompany
 {
   public:
        CCompany(void);  // Default constructor
        CCompany(const CCompany & b);  // Copy constructor
        bool NewAccount(const char * AccountID, int initialBalance);
        bool NewTranscation(const char * AccountID_SendFrom, const char * AccountID_SendTo, amount);
        CCompany ShowAllTransactions(const char * AccountID); // Function that shows all the transactions of the selected account
        int Balance(); // Shows actual account
        ...
        ...
        ...
    private:
          struct Transcaction
          {
            char AccountID[100];
            int InitialBalance;
            int ActualAccount;
            int *transactionAmount;
            int transactionCounter; 
          };
          Transcaction Transcactions[10000];
}


int main ( void )
{
CCompany c0;
assert(c0.NewAccount( "11111", 200 ));
assert(c0.NewAccount("66666", -600 ));
assert(c0.NewTranscation( "66666", "11111", 1000 ) );  // After this transaction>>>  11111: 1200, 66666: -1600
assert(c0.Account( "66666" ).Balance() == -1600 );

}
```

First of all, I would like to say that we cannot use STL, nor string, so vector or other STL containers are not possible to use. I choose struct array for the purpose of the task. If you have a better suggestion, just let me know. Also, we cannot use strings, but char array. It is perhaps because of learning how to allocate correctly memory, copy char array..

Anyway, I would like to ask two questions:

1) how to create a copy constructor for this class

2) I am not sure about this "assert ( x0 . Account ( "32322" ). Balance ( ) ==  -1600 );"
How to create a function Account which output goes to the input of the Balance() function.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Let's start here _1) how to create a copy constructor for this class_, you should be able to type that in google and get your answer. So there's no need to ask that here. As for your other question. Please specify the expected result, the result you're getting now, and the minimal code to reproduce your problem. Also, if you can't think of a title it basically already says that your question is too specific for SO

Comment: You know of the existence of _copy constructors_,  but not enough OO to ask "_How to create a function Account which output goes to the input of the Balance() function_". And a tip: use "11111" and "55555" for your example accounts, those two are too easily confused.

Comment: You need a type that represents accounts, and the `Balance` function should be there, not in `CCompany`.

Comment: Hello, everything you have in the example. THere are two accounts of one company with initial balance. There are also transactions - so some money are sent from one account to other account.
The command ''Account(accountID)'' shows all the transactions of the account. The command ''Account(accountID).Balance()'' should show actual balance of the account.
----------------
Account("11111")
Shows:
Account: 11111:
Initial balance: 200
Transactions:
 + 300, from: 6666
Actual balance: 1200
----------------
Account("11111").Balance()
Shows:
1200

Comment: @TheDoctorBombastic The `Account` function should return an object that represents an account and has a `Balance` function. It should not show the transactions. `ShowAllTransactions` should show the transactions, and it should not return a `CCompany`.

Comment: @molbdnilo: thanks, can you show me it?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have to rely on static allocation:

```cpp
Transcaction Transcactions[10000];
```

Well, do so the same with your accounts:

```cpp
Account accounts[1000];
```

You will have to create an appropriate account class, though, it might look similar to your transaction class with a member for id and balance. You might want to provide appropriate constructors to facilitate further work with it:

```cpp
struct Account
{
    char id[128];
    int balance;

    Account(char const* theId = nullptr, int balance = 0)
        : balance(balance)
    {
        if(theId)
        {
            strncpy(id, theId, sizeof(id));
            // just for the case of theId begin too long:
            id[sizeof(id) - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
    Account(Account const& other) = default;
};
```

Further details ommitted... Be aware that you get a default assignment operator, too.

Your transaction class, though, appears inappropriate to me. A transaction essentially requires a source account, a destination account and the amount to be transferred. Id is optional, but can be useful. Depending on your needs, you *could* use a pointer to the corresponding account instance or the index wihtin your companies account array:

```cpp
struct Transaction
{
    unsigned int id;
    unsigned int sourceAccountIndex; // alternative: pointer or id string
    unsigned int destinationAccountIndex;  // alternative: pointer or id string
    int amount;
};
```

Using indices or pointers, you get quicker access to the related accounts, however, you have to consider pointers/indices getting invalid if you're ever going to delete accounts again. This is not too difficult to cope with, if you don't want to, you still can keep the account id as you have now (but you need two of them!).

With the array class members, you get your copy constructor for free! Just declare it:

```cpp
Company(Company const& other) = default;
```

If you want or have to write the copy constructor explicitly, simply iterate over the arrays and copy the entries (normally, you'd prefer std::copy, but as STL is explicitly excluded...):

```cpp
Company::Company(Company const& other)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(accounts)/sizeof(*accounts); ++i)
    {
        accounts[i] = other.accounts[i];
    }
    // transactions analogously
}
```

Finally: Your account function would iterate over the entries and return the first account the id matches:

```cpp
Company::Account* Company::account(char const* id)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(accounts)/sizeof(*accounts); ++i)
    {
        if(strcmp(id, accounts[i].id) == 0)
        {
            return accounts + i;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

Variant of using pointers (the one I personally would prefer):

```cpp
Company::Account* Company::account(char const* id)
{
    Account* end = accounts + sizeof(accounts)/sizeof(*accounts);
    for(Account* a = accounts; a != end; ++a)
    {
        if(strcmp(id, a->id) == 0)
        {
            return a;
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

A last hint: with every new Transaction being created, do not forget to adjust the balances of the involved accounts!

Comment: Thank you very much, I am going to try it out, thanks for the effort.